# Linux cronjob wget to file instead of STDOUT

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, wget

I have a cronjob that was specified like this :
`0 * * * * root bash /data/daily.sh`

Inside this daily.sh is -> `/data/get.sh https://www.xxxxxxx.com/ccc/ 0`

As you can see, get.sh take two arguments, the first URL and the recursive depth. The script will call another get.sh with incremented depth counter and different url which is scrapped from the first run result and stop until it reaches certain depth.

Inside the get.sh, I am scrapping a website with this command

```
wget -O- $1 > main.htm
```

The problem is, main.htm is not created when this script is run via crontab. The log is saying it is saved to 'STDOUT', while when I manually run it it will save to 'main.htm'. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you try giving the full path to the main.htm file.

Comment: ah it works with combination for the answer below.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to file by doing the following.

```
wget -O {output-filename} $1
```